# Attach role to ApiGateway that have ability to write logs in CloudWatch via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Hi I need to enable cloudwatch logs for API Gateway. We use cloudformation to describe infrastructure. As said in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-account.html) I need to create role in my case I created such role:

```
  ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        -
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service:
              - "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: 'ApiGatewayLogsPolicy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "logs:*"
                Resource:
                  - "arn:aws:logs:::*"
```

and then I need to attach this role to api gateway account:

```
  ApiGatewayAccount:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Account
    Properties:
      CloudWatchRoleArn: !GetAtt ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole.Arn
```

as a result I receive such error during stack creation:

`The role ARN does not have required permissions set to API Gateway`

I search through internet and in all topics people suggest to add Trusted Policy with `apigateway.amazonaws.com` principal. But I already specified that and still get this error message.

Comment: Sometimes, IAM roles creation takes a little time to propagate. Did you try to create the API gateway account creation at the last possible minute?

Comment: Hi @krishna_mee2004, I run same template almost whole day with minor changes and it always fails on same step

Comment: Did you get this working? I am too stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got it working by using one of the AWS's managed policy.

```
ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      -
        Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          Service:
          - "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      Version: '2012-10-17'
    Path: /
    ManagedPolicyArns:
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting "CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging" there's a way to set this using cloudformation?

Comment: Please use this link for the solution: https://gist.github.com/villasv/4f5b62a772abe2c06525356f80299048